# Is there a CUDA equivalence of "-Wl,--stack,[a number, e.g. 4194304 for 4Mb of stack]" as in C++?

Tags: c++, cuda, stack

I'm relatively new to CUDA. When running a CUDA program I noticed that if I increase an array `x[ITERATION]` to certain length, i.e. ITERATION "sufficiently" large, the CUDA code will crash upon executing, while being compiled successfully.

In C++ I can do `g++ -Wl,--stack,4194304 program myCode.cc` to increase stack size to 4Mb, which solved the issue. Is there a way I can do this in CUDA? I tried `nvcc -Wl,--stack,4194304` but it's not working.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `x` really have to be on the stack?

Comment: @Frank hmm it's actually an array I declared within `int main(){}` which I used to store simulation samples. Simulation algorithm is done in GPU though so within GPU there will be another copy of this array `x`. Does is count as "on the stack"?

Comment: Your array will end up in local memory which is an amount of memory allocated for each thread in the grid on the device memory. With a large number of threads, you may run out of device memory, hence failure of the kernel launch. You may need poo rework your algorithm.

Comment: @Frank Reason to ask is that, once I increase `ITERATION` to a certain number, my CUDA code will crash albeit complied successfully. I checked CUDA architecture and it seems that I only used part of the thread memory within GPU, not all, but it still crashes.

Comment: cuda memory management depends on driver's build,  it may be unable to pull that large arrays from stack. Exhaustion of memory possible, but usually takes gigabyte or more of data. In general it is bad idea not to use heap with opengl, opencl or cuda

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET Apologise didn't see your message before sending off last comment to Frank. I don't think I've used all local memory though, so I'm just wondering if there is a maximum on stack size per thread?

Comment: there is on linux, and to degree on windows,  and even more so for driver/kernel module. And , if I'm not mistaken, on linux it is process-wide limit?

Comment: @Swift Thanks Swift! I'll try swapping stack with heap and see what comes out. Sorry I don't quite understand you 2nd comment (I'm a statistician not CS professional - limited CS knowledge on process-wide limit...)

Comment: If x is declared within a kernel, then, the amount of memory can ramp up very quickly. To verify this, can you send the launch configuration and hardware? If not, that is if x is declared in Cpu code, then you may pass arguments with the -Xcompiler switch in nvcc, or -Xlinker.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET Thanks for the info! I just used `nvcc cudaCode.cu` in command line, then `./a.out` (it's in linux) to launch. The hardware is Nvidia Tesla P100. By `-Xcompiler/-Xlinker` do you mean something like `nvcc -Xlinker -Wl,--stack,[a number for stack size] cudaCode.cu`?

Comment: Do you need the array on the stack in the first place? If the data is common for all threads, why not declare it on heap instead? Each thread will see the same array and the memory would be consumed only once, instead of thousants of times! For CUDA heap allocation czeck `cudaMalloc`, `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaFree`.

Comment: Cuda stack is very shallow. 1KB of stack/thread may still be reasonable. 100KB/thread may be too much already!

Comment: @CygnusX1 Thanks! I don't know that stack is so slower than heap. Is this true for C/C++ as well?

Comment: By "slower" you mean "smaller"? C++ can have big stacks because CPU handles just a few threads at a time. CUDA runs thousants and there is simply not enough main memory to assign a big stack for each. For example: 10000 threads x 100KB of stack = 1GB of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can control the size of the stack. It is set at run-time, before the kernel launches, through the API function:

```
cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimit limit, size_t value)
```

The `limit` is an enum, which specifies which limit you want to control. In your case it would be `cudaLimitStackSize`. The second argument `value` is the size in bytes of that stack.

[Full documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g05956f16eaa47ef3a4efee84563ccb7d)

Be careful with the stack size however. CUDA programs tend to have thousants of threads running concurrently and the system will maintain the stack memory for all the threads at all times. As a result, you may run out of memory fairly quickly.

For example, if you aim for 4MB stack memory and you run 60 blocks with 512 threads in each (those are resonable values!) - that will be 60*512*4MB = ~30GB of device memory consumed. Most GPUs have less memory than that.

Usually big arrays are best shared among all the threads instead.

Comment: Many thanks! It saves my life! Just out of curiosity, if `x[ITERATION]` is only to be used in CPU, i.e. `__host__` functions, is there an equivalence of `cudaDeviceSetLimit`? I tried to search in the full documentation but couldn't find anything

Comment: Min, that is a harder question. Main thread has its stack allocated by OS. You would need to dig into OS then to change the limit. Secondary threads that you spawn - you may be able to control that. pthreads have `pthread_attr_setstacksize` for example. If you are interested, I suggest you do your research on this.